# Hide and show button in react

Tags: reactjs

I have one div element and inside it has one button A. and there is button B outside which is hidden by default
so when I click button A, the whole div should hide including button A, and also it should display the hidden button B.
And when I click button B, it should open the div and hide.
How can I achieve this in reactjs.
This is what I have tried, but it is not showing any button on the screen

```
import React from 'react'
import useState from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  const [show,setShow]=useState(true)
return(
  <>
  {show && <div>
  Hello
  <button>button A</button>
  </div>}
  
  <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>button 2</button>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Please add some things you have tried yourself first. This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Would you be happy with an answer which is just text, no code? If not, consider including your code in the question.

Comment: @DBS Can you please check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how this code is setting and using the `show` boolean state value for Button A and Button B.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)
  return (
    <div>
      {show && <div>
        Hello
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Button A</button>
      </div>}

      {!show &&
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>
        Button B
        </button>
      }
    </div>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Note: Make sure you're importing `useState` from `'react'` in your code. I had to write it as `const {useState} = React;` in order to get the above code snippet to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ToogelButton({ children }) {

  // React state to manage visibility
  const [showButtonB, setShowButtonB] = useState(false);

  // function to toggle the boolean value
  function toggleShow() {
    setShowButtonB(showButtonB => !showButtonB);
  }
  
  if(showButtonB) {
    return (
        // Button B
        <button onClick={toggleShow}>BUTTON B</button>
      );
  }
  

  return (
    // Button A and content
    <div className="container">
      Test Content
      <button onClick={toggleShow}>BUTTON A</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, when you set a state value based on the previous state, you should use the callback approach to avoid skipping state changes that have occurred but not been rendered yet, e.g. `setShowButtonB(previousValue => !previousValue);` (Probably not an issue in this case, but worth pointing out)